# I would appreciate a little help in understanding the error in pine script

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I'm trying to get a value of 5 if the chart is in a 5 minute time frame and every hour the clock shows 5 minutes, For example: 13:05, 14:05

I wrote this line:

```
res=  (timeframe.period == '5') and (minute == '5') ? 5 :na
```

This is the error I am getting :

> Cannot call 'operator ==' with argument 'expr1'='5'. An argument of
> 'literal string' type was used but a 'series int' is expected

I tried to write it that way too:

```
res=  (timeframe.period == '5') ? (minute == '5') ? 5 :na
```

And I got this error:

> Mismatched input 'end of line without line continuation' expecting ':'

I would like to know if it is possible to write it differently and if it is even possible?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `res= (timeframe.period == '5') and (minute == 5) ? 5 :na`?

It seems to be that you're trying to compare with a string a value of an int array

Comment: Indeed, I tried and this is the error:

Cannot call 'request.security' with argument 'timeframe'='r'. An argument of 'series int' type was used but a 'simple string' is expected

I understand that there is a problem comparing a string with an int array, I believe there is a way to solve it

Thanks for trying to help

Answer (score 0):

`minute` returns an `int` and not a `string`.

> minute(time) → series int

So, you should be doing `res=  (timeframe.period == '5') and (minute == 5) ? 5 :na`

Always consult with the [reference manual](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v5/) when in doubt.

Comment: Thanks, I tried, this is the error I got:

Cannot call 'request.security' with argument 'timeframe'='r'. An argument of 'series int' type was used but a 'simple string' is expected

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: Run the same script on several different time frames, because 'request.security' is limited to 40

For example: a time frame of 5 minutes and every 5 minutes a value of 5 will be received and the script will enter data into 'request.security' according to a resolution of 5 minutes

Another time frame of 15 minutes, and every 15 minutes, a value of 15 will be received and the script will insert data into 'request.security' according to a resolution of 15 minutes

Hope it's clearer now

Comment: That wouldn't work. The limit is 40, there is no workaround for this.

Comment: I thought about it again, why wouldn't it be possible to write a condition in the script that every minute (the script is loaded and re-run every minute) will check 40 different 'request.security'?